# How to document curried functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've not found any documentation about how curried functions should be documented. Lets asume we have the following function:

```
const push = browserHistory => route => browserHistory.push(route)
```

Is this a valid documentation?

```
/**
 * @param {Object} browserHistory 
 * @param {string} route
 */
const push = browserHistory => route => browserHistory.push(route)
```

Comment: Maybe ask [code reviewers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) about general documentation techniques?

Comment: Functional programming has a long way to go in JavaScript

Comment: You could go with [@callback](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-callback.html)s, but that's sub-optimal, especially considering your second function doesn't have a name.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it apepars to be on best practices of software engineers